# Unable to load dll 'webview2loader.dll' the specified module could not be found

Tags: winforms, webview2

I am using Webview2 as replacement for old IE based WebBrowser Control in WinForms application. In Dev Environment I am able to successfully run the application. I have installed Microsoft Edge Insider Channel as part of setting Development machine as per Microsoft guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/machine-setup . Locally in my development build repository, inside runtime folder I can find webview2loader.dll which is successfully running an application locally.

But after Deployment on Test environment, I am getting below error

"Unable to load dll 'webview2loader.dll' the specified module could not be found"

App is hosted on server and from there, clients are downloading the executable folder locally on their machine and running the application.

After downloading executable folder, Runtime folder is not created and no webview2loader.dll present under executable folder

So did anything missing on server? Did Clients need to do some configuration to run the application?

Comment: 1) You need to follow [Distribute your app and the WebView2 Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution). 2) In the target machines, you should find in the executable directory a Folder named `runtimes` contains `win-arm64`, `win-x64`, and `win-x86` folders, each of which contains its own `native` folder which contains `WebView2Loader.dll`. 3) Also, you should find `Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll`, `Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.dll`, and `Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf.dll` libs...

Comment: If the hosting machine already has the WebView2 Runtime (pre-installed or it's a Windows 11 machine), you just need `*.WebView2.WinForms.dll`, `*.WebView2.WinForms.dll` and `WebView2Loader.dll` (usually the x64 version) in the same folder as your executable's -- `Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf.dll` is not required, if it's a *pure* WinForms app

Comment: Of course, packing your app is a quite better approach, so either use the provided [standard package installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/samples/wv2deploymentvsinstallersample) or the provided [WiX Custom Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/samples/wv2deploymentwixcustomactionsample) (or [Burn Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/samples/wv2deploymentwixburnbundlesample))