# Unable to locate WebView2Loader.dll

Tags: webview2

I am trying to make an internet browser form using the TEdgeBrowser component of C++ Builder. I have read ([Unable to load dll 'webview2loader.dll' the specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74217709/unable-to-load-dll-webview2loader-dll-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) among others) that I need several dll,s like WebView2Loader.dll. I have checked that WebView2 is installed on my system, but I can't find these dll,s.

The question is: where do I find these dll,s on a Windows 10 machine?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is discussed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#files-to-ship-with-the-app. You can get WebView2Loader.dll from the WebView2 nuget package

Comment: Thank you, David. As I said in my ticket, I have installed WebView2 on the system, but I can't find the famous dll. Best regards.

Comment: There are two WebView2 related products: the WebView2 Runtime which gets installed on the user's machine, and the WebView2 SDK which you need to download and incorporate into your app. The WebView2 SDK contains the WebView2Loader.DLL. The WebView2 Runtime does not. You won't find WebView2Loader.DLL on the OS but rather in the WebView2 SDK.

Comment: Thank you. Although I had already done it before posting the post, I have downloaded again what is supposed to be necessary from this page https://developer.microsoft.com/es-es/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section. But the installer doesn't even want to start because it says that WebView2 is already installed on the system. It doesn't say anything about the SDK there, but all the pages I've looked at asking for the SDK take me to that page. So either I can't find the right place to download the SDK, or I'm missing something.